# How to fixed Project Permission Denied problem for update draft grade and assigned grade of student submission from Google Classroom

Tags: php, google-oauth, google-api-php-client, google-api-client, google-classroom

I want to update the draft grade and assigned grade from Google Classroom using API. The following problem is seen When I test to update the draft grade and assigned grades using [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/patch?apix_params=%7B%22courseId%22%3A%22328776504166%22%2C%22courseWorkId%22%3A%22361223650991%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22Cg0IiOu99CkQr_3t1MEK%22%2C%22updateMask%22%3A%22draftGrade%2CassignedGrade%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22draftGrade%22%3A40%2C%22assignedGrade%22%3A100%7D%7D).

**Problem:1**

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "@ProjectPermissionDenied The Developer Console project is not permitted to make this request.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

[image: Shows a pop-up error message:]

This error may be due to using an insufficient credential type.
Try using OAuth 2.0.

**Localhost Code:**

```
$client = getClient();
        $service = new Google_Service_Classroom($client);
        $courseId = '393351980716';
        $courseWorkId = '393445838699';
        $id = 'Cg0Iu5q5vHkQ657M2bkL';
        $post_body = new Google_Service_Classroom_StudentSubmission(array(
            'assignedGrade' => 10,
            'draftGrade' => 90
        ));
        $params = array(
            'updateMask' => 'assignedGrade,draftGrade'
          );

        $list = $service->courses_courseWork_studentSubmissions->patch($courseId, $courseWorkId, $id, $post_body,$params);
```

Then when I run the above code on localhost I see problem-2:

**Problem-2**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Google\Service\Exception: {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "@ProjectPermissionDenied The Developer Console project is not pe
rmitted to make this request.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "@ProjectPermissionDenied The Developer Console project is no
t permitted to make this request.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

**How to solve this problem?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Classroom API [documentation](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/Access.Errors):

> `ProjectPermissionDenied` indicates that the request attempted to modify a resource associated with a different Developer Console project.
>
> *Possible Action*: Indicate that your application cannot make the desired request. It can only be made by the Developer Console project of the OAuth client ID that created the resource.

Therefore, if the resource you are trying to modify has been created manually for instance, this means that it is not associated with any developer project, hence the error you are receiving.

You will have to create these resources in the same project in order to be able to execute this request successfully.

#### Reference

- [Classroom API Access Errors](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/Access.Errors).

Comment: Now I can update draft grade using the environment of **Try this API** cause I created a course manually where "associated with developer": true . But I can't  update draft grade using localhost. I've updated my question Now The above problem-2 PERMISSION_DENIED appear whenever I want to update the draft grade from localhost. How to solve problem-2.

Answer (score 0):

For that API request your API key needs one of the following authorised scopes

> Authorization Scopes
> Requires one of the following OAuth scopes:
>
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.students
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.me

Comment: Already I have added those scope.  But I can't update draft grade using localhost.  Now The above problem-2 PERMISSION_DENIED appear whenever I want to update the draft grade from localhost. How to solve problem-2.